# Was the Hard & Soft Master’s younger brother, Tommy’s father, an Arashikage ninja too?

Tags: gi-joe

In the *G.I. Joe: A Real American Hero* (Marvel comics) canon, was Storm Shadow’s father an Arashikage ninja too?

We are introduced to the Arashikage ninja clan in *G.I. Joe* #21, “Silent Interlude,” confirming Snake Eyes & Stormshadow wear the same I-Ching hexagram, later confirmed to be the symbol of the Arashikage ninjas.
[image: Arashikage ninja hexagram]

A few issues later, we’re treated to part of the origin story. The head of the clan at that time was known as the Hard Master. He and his brother, the Soft Master, gave their nephew, Thomas Arashikage an important role. The Soft Master recounts this story to Snake-Eyes in *G.I. Joe* #26, confirming it was:
[image: Late Younger Brother]

> The only son of my late younger brother…”

**Was Storm Shadow’s father ever an Arashikage ninja within the *ARAH* continuity?**